# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in for loop when filling a table

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to fill a table, but I'm getting the following error: 
"Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" and don't know how to solve this, this is my code:

```
   for i= 1:19
    nom=strcat('App\africa\',int2str(i),'.jpg');
    Table_Img(i,:)=nom; 
   end
```

I read many discussions about this error, but none of the given solutions solved my issue. Thanks for your replies. PS:I'm using matlab2011a

Comment: Sorry, you're right about this, I forgot to change the dimension of the table, but I get the previous error even when I try to put just the name of the image. I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that

```
int2str(1) = '1'
int2str(10) = '10'
```

The first is a string of length 1, while the length of the second is 2. You cannot put strings of different length into the same matrix without triggering the dimension mismatch error. That is what happens in your example.

You have several choices.

#### 1. Use filenames of constant length

One choice would be to rename the files so that the first file would be `01.jpg` instead of `1.jpg`

Then you can use

```
sprintf('%02d.jpg',i)
```

instead of

```
int2str(i)
```

#### 2. Pad the lines with zeros.

Assume that 255 characters would be enough to hold a filename

```
Table_Img = zeros(19,255)
for i= 1:19
    nom=strcat('App\africa\',int2str(i),'.jpg');
    Table_Img(i,1:length(nom))=nom; 
end
```

Now when you actually need to use the file names trim the zeros at the end. For example, using the `find` function to pick only the nonzero characters from the table

```
nom = char(Table_Img(find(Table_Img(1,:))))
```

instead of

```
nom = Table_Img(1,:)
```

as in the first suggestion